# Convergence of Newton method and machine precision

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, machine-precision

I implemented the Newton method to find the non-zero root of $f(x) = 1-bx-e^{-x}$ in Excel and I have tested it for various values of $0<b<1$. However, what I am seeing for some values of $b$ (e.g. $b=0.9$) is that the solutions oscillates around some values without converging. (My starting value is $x_0 = 1/b$.) As far as I can tell, all the requirements for the quadratic convergence of the method are satisfied, so I was excepting the solution to converge, but the results oscillate around the solution with absolute error of $err \approx  5.55E-15$. Since for doubles the machine precision is $\epsilon = 2^{-52}\approx 2.22E-16$ it seems to me that there is something else at play. However, peculiarly, $err/\epsilon = 25.0$ exactly (within Excel's precision).

So, I guess my question is: how can I determine whether a convergence has been reached within machine precision?

Comment: If you have a few different machine errors that happen to align in the same direction, machine errors can pile up to be larger than machine epsilon, even much larger than that. This is part of why machine epsilon is so small, because in practice we expect floating point truncation to cause significantly more error than one machine epsilon worth.

Comment: One thing that might improve things a little bit would be to shift your function, looking at $g(x)=f(x+1/b)=-bx-e^{-(x+1/b)}$ beginning at $x=0$. This would remove a little bit of cancellation in the computation of $1-bx$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for your reply. Yes, indeed, I am aware of "catastrophic cancelations" etc. But given some function, how can I word out what this maximum error could be? Thanks again.

Comment: It would be extremely tedious to determine that; part of the point of the IEEE standard is that the direction of a machine error is supposed to (in a practical calculation) oscillate back and forth so that we can do, say, a billion floating point operations and expect the error to be significantly less than a billion machine epsilons at the end of the computation.

Comment: As a practical matter, if your relative error is less than $10^{-12}$ and you aren't writing a library function intended to be called over and over in a more complicated algorithm (like the standard floating point routines), then you're probably OK.

Comment: At the solution for $b=0.9$ the denominator $-b+e^{-x}$ is about $0.1$ which along with the sum of the absolute values in the numerator gives a magnification factor for floating point errors of up to about $20$, which seems in line with your observations..